# QuickBooks Release Number

Tags: quickbooks

Is there any way to get the release number of the QuickBooks software using SDK 12.0? If not, does the major/minor versions retrieved by a Host Query have any relationship to the release number?

PS I'm NOT talking about the release number of the QBXML.

Thanks,

Larry

Answer (score 1):

The Host query does return the "Product Name" which has the release number. Here is an example of a host Query result

```
        <HostQueryRs statusCode="0" statusSeverity="Info" statusMessage="Status OK">
        <HostRet>
            <ProductName>Intuit QuickBooks Enterprise Solutions: Accountant 12.0</ProductName>
            <MajorVersion>22</MajorVersion>
            <MinorVersion>0</MinorVersion>
            <SupportedQBXMLVersion>1.0</SupportedQBXMLVersion>
            <SupportedQBXMLVersion>1.1</SupportedQBXMLVersion>
            <SupportedQBXMLVersion>2.0</SupportedQBXMLVersion>
            <SupportedQBXMLVersion>2.1</SupportedQBXMLVersion>
            <SupportedQBXMLVersion>3.0</SupportedQBXMLVersion>
            <SupportedQBXMLVersion>4.0</SupportedQBXMLVersion>
            <SupportedQBXMLVersion>4.1</SupportedQBXMLVersion>
            <SupportedQBXMLVersion>5.0</SupportedQBXMLVersion>
            <SupportedQBXMLVersion>6.0</SupportedQBXMLVersion>
            <SupportedQBXMLVersion>7.0</SupportedQBXMLVersion>
            <SupportedQBXMLVersion>8.0</SupportedQBXMLVersion>
            <SupportedQBXMLVersion>9.0</SupportedQBXMLVersion>
            <SupportedQBXMLVersion>10.0</SupportedQBXMLVersion>
            <SupportedQBXMLVersion>11.0</SupportedQBXMLVersion>
        </HostRet>
    </HostQueryRs>
```